# what cloud API to use - simplecloud?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, azure, cloud

I work for a company which is developing a media asset management website. We've decided to modify our web app to host our media on the cloud. We will license this web application to our customers and allow them to choose whatever cloud service they want. Currently we are using Amazon S3 and I manually upload the files using cloudberry. But now we need to write an application which will mirror whatever is in our local media directory to Amazon. It's all ASP.net and I've researched ThreeSharp and other simple C# cloud APIs for S3. But now I see that Zend and Microsoft have partnered for this simplecloud initiative which apparently only works for PHP.

Question: Does anyone know of a simple cloud api (simplecloud.org) which works with all popular cloud services for .NET?

I would really hate to have to write the same code to move and delete files three different times for Azure, S3 and RackSpace or have to reinvent the wheel.

best,
Tuviah

Comment: sounds interesting, I would like to learn more from people with S3 experience too.

Comment: Hi Tuviah, it's been two year since you asked this question, what solution you've used eventually? I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There's some of those on CodePlex:

- http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/
- http://cloudstorageapi.codeplex.com/